# Saving instance results in duplicate

Tags: python, django

So I have a CreateView that is actually a UpdateView . I want the not yet saved instance to be used to add other objects to it. That is why I override get_object(self)

```
    def get_object(self):
        form = self.get_form()
        form.instance.is_stub = True
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.save()
        return form.instance
```

When save & continue editing is pressed form_valid() is called:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.is_stub = False
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            self.object.save()

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

However form_valid creates a new instance and it loses the related fields that were linked.
How do I prevent this? I manually link related fields in the UpdateView for example: Add author to publication.authors. But the publication gets incremented and the data is lost after form_valid.

Complete view:

```
class PublicationCreate(UpdateView):
    '''
    inherits CreateView
    Uses template for creating/updating.
    Uses standard edit/new form (NewCrispyForm)
    redirect to publication main page (publication show)
    '''
    template_name = 'publications/form_create.html'
    form_class = NewCrispyForm
    context_object_name = 'publication'
    model = Publication
```

```
    def get_success_url(self):
        """Detect the submit button used and act accordingly"""
        if self.request.POST.get("save_add_another"):
            return '/publication/new/'
        elif self.request.POST.get("save_and_continue_editing") :
            return '/publication/' + str(self.object.id) + '/edit/'
        elif self.request.POST.get("save"):
            url = self.request.GET.get('next')
            if url == None:
                return '/publication/' + str(self.object.id) + '/edit/'
            if self.request.GET.get('q'):
                url += '?q=' + self.request.GET.get('q')
            if self.request.GET.get('page'):
                url += '&page=' + self.request.GET.get('page')
            if self.request.GET.get('order_by'):
                url += '&order_by=' + self.request.GET.get('order_by')
            if self.request.GET.get('direction'):
                url += '&direction=' + self.request.GET.get('direction')
            return url
```

Comment: to do that functionality is better to use model inlineformsets  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: This does not inherit from `CreateView` though, what are you talking about? Also your `get_object` and `form_valid` methods are not present here?

Comment: I already gave those methods they are present. Like I said it is actually a UpdateView I needed to access publication when adding for example: authors,translators and uploadedfiles.